# To change trains = cambiare treno?

Tags: meaning

I have read the following sentence:

> Cambieremo treno alla prossima stazione.

Is "cambiare treno" the most usual form of expressing "to change trains" in Italian? Are there other usual alternatives (e.g., "cambiare un treno", "cambiare i treni")?

Comment: Attenzione: “prossima”, non *“proxima”.

Comment: @DaG. It is a common mistake of mine. I have fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if the context is clear, one can omit both "treno" and "stazione". "Cambiamo alla prossima".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“Cambiare treno” è l’espressione generalmente usata:

Da [*Il mondo dentro. Per cambiare il mondo fuori*](https://books.google.it/books?id=FYuNDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT74&dq=%22cambiare%20treno%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjno_EleDkAhUKxIsKHa0bDewQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22cambiare%20treno%22&f=false) di Andrea Pilati:

> E ora, aperti gli occhi, *consci di dover cambiare treno*, ci troviamo fermi alla stazione, valigie in mano piene di esperienze e magari con marito o moglie...

Da [*Un treno pieno di vento*](https://books.google.it/books?id=Fm8k91P1M_EC&pg=PT10&dq=%22cambiare%20treno%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjno_EleDkAhUKxIsKHa0bDewQ6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=%22cambiare%20treno%22&f=false) di Rae Meadows:

> *Al momento di cambiare treno* a Charlottesville, lei e Violet si erano ricongiunte.

Vedi anche “[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese-italiano/to-change-trains-buses-at-) ”.